# как в.kv файле задать определеное количество шаблонов из .py

Tags: python, kivy, android-scrollview

есть 2 файла MainForm.kv и main.py
В MainForm.kv находиться ScrollView:

```
 ScrollView:
    do_scroll_x: 0
    GridLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,1,1,1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        cols: 1
        size_hint: .98, None
        height: 1000
        width: 335
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: 1, .25
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                Label: 
                    text: '[color=000000]NaN[/color]'
                    size_hint: .6, 1
                    markup: True
                Button: 
                    text: '-'
                    size_hint: .14, 1
                Label:
                    text: '[color=000000]0[/color]'
                    markup: True
                    size_hint: .12, 1
                Button: 
                    text: '+'
                    size_hint: .14, 1
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: 1, .25
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                Label: 
                    text: '[color=000000]NaN[/color]'
                    size_hint: .6, 1
                    markup: True
                Button: 
                    text: '-'
                    size_hint: .14, 1
                Label:
                    text: '[color=000000]0[/color]'
                    markup: True
                    size_hint: .12, 1
                Button: 
                    text: '+'
                    size_hint: .14, 1
```

шаблон:

```
    BoxLayout:
    size_hint: 1, .25
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label: 
        text: '[color=000000]NaN[/color]'
        size_hint: .6, 1
        markup: True
    Button: 
        text: '-'
        size_hint: .14, 1
    Label:
        text: '[color=000000]0[/color]'
        markup: True
        size_hint: .12, 1
    Button: 
        text: '+'
        size_hint: .14, 1
```

[image: шаблон]

как вставлять этих шаблонов в ScrollView столько, сколько будет задано в main.py?

Answer (score 2):

Создайте класс шаблона:

```
<MyTemplate@BoxLayout>:
    size_hint: 1, .25
    orientation: 'horizontal'

    Label: 
        text: '[color=000000]NaN[/color]'
        size_hint: .6, 1
        markup: True

    Button: 
        text: '-'
        size_hint: .14, 1

    Label:
        text: '[color=000000]0[/color]'
        markup: True
        size_hint: .12, 1

    Button: 
        text: '+'
        size_hint: .14, 1
```

Дайте id вашему боксу, куда хотите добавлять шаблон:

```
ScrollView:
    do_scroll_x: 0

    GridLayout:
        id: box
```

И далее в main.py:

```
self.ids.box.add_widget(
    Factory.MyTemplate()
)
```